# Is there a way to get the name of the method or sub that is running in VB.Net when catching an error?

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I'm betting this is obvious, but for CUSTOMER debugging purposes, I need to know the name of the routine causing the error.

I'm sure there's a way to do this -

Private Sub DoSomething (s as String)

Try

some bad code here

Catch

msgbox ("The error is in routine - " & the method or sub)
End Try

End Sub

Note - I am NOT looking for a #DEBUG directive...this is for release code

Thanks.

Comment: `Catch ex As Exception` Then `ex.TargetSite` (or `ex.StackTrace` for more details).

Comment: That's what I'm after, thank you...